# Android debugger weirdness

Tags: android, debugging

I've been having frustrating issues with the Android debugger. I can debug and step through code sometimes, then in other parts of the code (lately in try/catch situations), it goes down to the catch {} block and there is no information on the exception and it doesn't even Log.e it to console. Notice how in the screenshot I've stepped into the catch block, but there is no live variable context, its as if it is in normal content assist mode. Watch expressions show **<error(s)_during_the_evaluation>.**

[image: exception]

Can anyone shed light on these frustrating issues I'm having? The weird thing that the debugger works fine in other parts of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse + ADT is notorious for acting [inconsistently](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27940#c25), which often leads me to just make sure that `Project > Build Automatically` is checked and then simply fire up a `Project > Clean...`.

Sometimes even that doesn't help. So I just close Eclipse and re-start it. Works most of the time.

When even this doesn't help, I close Eclipse, run `CCleaner` and reboot. **Works every time**.

Weird but true.

Comment: [CCleaner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCleaner) is a system-wide cache purger for Windows (at least that's what I use it for, I don't trust it enough to touch my registry). If you are using Linux, the equivalent would be [BleachBit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BleachBit)

Answer (score 1):

You can't *always* believe your debugger; it's an inexact science. This is especially true when there are multiple code build steps (JVM bytecode, Dalvik code, etc). The debugger often doesn't have 100% of the information necessary to reverse engineer the location in the code back to a source code line.

In the instance above, did your code *actually* throw an exception, or not? It sounds like it didn't, and the debugger is showing execution on that highlighted line even though it's not really going to execute it.

I would be more inclined to believe the execution of the code - if `Log.e()` was never called, then you never really got any exception at all.

Comment: Yes I have similar thoughts, but how does that help me when I'm trying to work out whether it threw the exception. How can I really know if it threw the exception if the debugger continuously steps into it?

Comment: Rely on logging. Put something like `Log.e("Success!")` at the end of the `try` block, and see if that gets logged.